# Getting rid of cell text background box

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing

I have this table:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kFg09.png]

How do I get rid of the boxes behind the text?

This is my current code:

```
    UIColor *CellColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:0.2];
    cell.backgroundColor = CellColor;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title text...";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Subtitle text...";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default background color for a UILabel is white. So this is normal.

If you want a transparent background, you need to use:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor ];
```

And same for `detailTextLabel`

Comment: No, I want the text color to be white, it's the odd square behind the text I want gone. If I follow your suggestion the text disappears and the square stays.

Comment: cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor ]; did the trick